# Proving direct sum given linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$ such that $T^2 = T$. 
Define $W_1 = \{ u \in V  :\,  T(u) = u\},\; W_2 = \{u \in V: T(u) = 0\}$
which are subspaces of $V$. 
Prove that $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$  (direct sum).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: That $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$ is pretty clear. Now note that for all $v\in V$, $v = v + T(v) - T(v)$.

Comment: Hi. I managed to show that W1 ∩ W2 = {0}.
This is wad I did for the latter part.
Taking any v ∈ V, 
define w1 = 0.5( v + T(v)) and w2 = 0.5( v - T(v)).
so w1 + w2 = v
T(w2) = T(0.5 (v - T(v)))
      = 0.5[ T(v) - T2(v)]
      = 0.5[ T(v) - T(v)]
      = 0
=> w2 ∈ W2.
T(w1) = T(0.5(v + T(v)))
      = 0.5[ T(v) + T2(v)]
      = 0.5 [ T(v) + T(v)] 
      = T(v)
Im stuck here. Not sure how to show that w1 ∈ W1..

Comment: Take instead $w_1 = T(v)$ and $w_2 = v-T(v)$, your $w_1$ is not in $W_1$!

Comment: oh! i see!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! =D